# подскажите пожалуйста как правильней портировать код с с++ на JAVA?

Tags: java, c++

вот с++ вариант ->

```
Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& other) const {
    Vector result = *this;
    
    result.x += other.x;
    result.y += other.y;

    return result;
}
```

вот вариант Java ->

```
    public Vector sum(Vector other) {
        Vector result = this;

        result.x += other.x;
        result.y += other.y;

        return result;
    }
```

не знаю насколько они идентичны в использование,но результат выводит на джаве странный.
Возможно я не так вызываю метод в мейне? вот мейн :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот результат :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть примерно так : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну по результату вроде все нормально, только вывод не округляется до пятого знака. Ну и по умолчанию объекты преобразуются в строку методом `toString`, у которого реализация выглядит так: `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. Если хотите другой вывод, перепишите его со своим результатом `"(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")"`

Comment: у меня уже есть метод Print с этим -> "("+this.x+", " + this.y + ")"; вопрос немного в другом.У меня есть метод sum который я портировал с с++,но в с++ есть перегрузка операторов,а в Java нету.И при использование метода sum выводиться мусор или адрес чего-то,вот **Vector@24d46ca6**,нужно что бы вывело : допустим (6, 8)

Comment: возможно я что-то не так использую?или неправильно вызвал метод sum

Comment: @egor не игнорируйте то, что вам написали. Написали же, что в `println` выводится странно потому, что нет переопределенного метода `toString` и используется по умолчанию, а он выводит в таком формате.

Comment: а,я понял что вы иммели ввиду про toString,но я все равно не разобрался как использовать ниже прописаное вами

Comment: Главная проблема и неэквивалентность в `Vector result = *this;` в С++ тут стоздается копия объекта, а java версии у вас меняется исходный.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я не игнорировал,просто не так понял).Тогда подскажите как можно поменять формат?

Comment: Напишите у себя в классе `@Override public String toString() { return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")"; }`

Comment: Что касается вывода, то покажите код на С++, который выводит. И не нужно добавлять скриншоты, копируйте текст.

Comment: @RomanKonoval самое последнее фото,это вывод в с++,а код я написал выше

Comment: В этом вопросе все должно быть в тексте. А код main java у вас - скриншотом, вывод тоже. Далее, нужен код на С++, который выводит на экран. Его нету в вопросе.

Comment: в с++ у меня спокойно выводит это ```cout << x.sum(y) <<endl;```

Comment: @AlexKrass в какой части кода или методе?потому что не компилит

Comment: спасибо,вроде получилось